# csvHelper add new column beside last one

Tags: c#, csvhelper

Edit, thank you for the suggestion of using csvhelper, this is actually helping quite a lot.

What I have done is create a new method like so:

```
    public static void AppendFile<T>(FileInfo fi, List<T> report)
    {
        var settings = new CsvConfiguration(new CultureInfo("en-GB"))
        {
            //Delimiter = ";"
        };


        using var stream = File.Open(fi.FullName, FileMode.Append);

        using var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, settings))
        {
            csv.WriteRecords(report);
        }

    }
```

And gone through the example on the csvhelper site, creating a new class:

```
    public class Foo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

and then creating a new list:

```
    public class Foo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

and calling it like so:

```
AppendToFile.AppendFile(exportFile, records1);
```

This is working better than what I had before but, instead adding the new columns beside the last column, they are getting added at the bottom of the file.

For clarification,

what I'm trying to do:

[image]

what I'm getting:

[image]

As you'll be able to see, it's just being added as new rows rather than being separate columns, what do I need to change?

Comment: so you don't want to some values with comma won't be separated in a **"Comma Separated Value"** format... I'ts possible, you need to change de CSV default delimiter

Comment: I am aware of what csv stands for, this is how I've been asked to do this

Comment: If a file should contain Comma Separated Values but then fails to properly separate them adding a comma between the text of a single field without any delimiter to surround a field then it is broken from the start. Are you in control how these files are written?

Comment: The purpose of the application is to grab values from a database and place them into a csv file, for any of the fields if there are multiple entries, these values will be combined into a single cell separated by comma

Comment: As I said, change de delimiter inside that 'single' cell, or don't use csv format if you  **need** to add a comma INSIDE 'cell' values

Comment: I am not able to just change that as you've said , as I've said this is how I've been asked to do it, I cannot just simply change how it's made up

Comment: [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out a way that worked for me, might not be the most efficient but it does work.

```
    public static void AppendFile(FileInfo fi, List<string> newColumns, DataTable newRows)
    {
        var settings = new CsvConfiguration(new CultureInfo("en-GB"))
        {
            Delimiter = ";"

        };


        var dt = new DataTable();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(fi.FullName))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            using (var dataReader = new CsvDataReader(csv))
            {

                dt.Load(dataReader);

                foreach (var title in newColumns)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(title);
                }
                dt.Rows.Clear();

                foreach (DataRow row in newRows.Rows)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
                }
            }

        }

        using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fi.FullName);
        using var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, settings);
        // Write columns
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)

        {
            csvWriter.WriteField(column.ColumnName);
        }
        csvWriter.NextRecord();

        // Write row values
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                csvWriter.WriteField(row[i]);
            }
            csvWriter.NextRecord();
        }


    }
```

I start by getting the contents of the csv file into a data table and then adding in the new columns that I need. I then clear all the rows in the datatable and add new ones in (the data that is removed is added back in via the newRows parameter) and then write the datatable to the csv file

Answer (score 2):

Another way you can accomplish your goal is to write each object to the row by hand using `csvWriter.WriteHeader` and `csvWriter.WriteRecord`.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var settings = new CsvConfiguration(new CultureInfo("en-GB"))
    {
        Delimiter = ";"

    };
    
    var fooList = new List<Foo>()
    {
        new Foo { Id = 67, Name = "test1,test2"}
    };
    
    List<MyClass> records;

    using (var reader = new StringReader("Author,Admin Owner\nChris Jones,\nJohn Thompson,\nBrian Oates,"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        records = csv.GetRecords<MyClass>().ToList();
    }
    
    using var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, settings);
    
    csvWriter.WriteHeader<MyClass>();
    csvWriter.WriteHeader<Foo>();
    csvWriter.NextRecord();
    
    var i = 0;
    
    foreach (var record in records)
    {
        csvWriter.WriteRecord(record);
        
        if (i < fooList.Count())
        {
            csvWriter.WriteRecord(fooList[i]);
        }
        
        csvWriter.NextRecord();
        
        i++;
    }
    
}

public class MyClass
{
    public string Author { get; set; }
    [Name("Admin Owner")]
    public string AdminOwner { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, I will bare this in mind for future use!